# How do I pass properties while running java application generated using distTar command?

Tags: java, gradle

Normally if I were to run `.jar` file, then I can pass properties like

```bash
$ java -Dfoo=bar -jar my_application.jar
```

And my_application will be able to access the value of foo.

But while trying to run the file generated by distTar it is not able to access the value of foo.

I generated tar file using

```bash
$ ./gradlew distTar
$ tar -xvf build/distributions/my_application-1.0.tar
$ my_application-1.0/bin/my_application -Dfoo=bar
```

My application is not able to get the value of foo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So turns out we have to pass it as an environment variable. If I open my_application-1.0/bin/my_application, there is comment something like

```bash
# Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and MY_APPLICATION_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
```

So all I needed to do was to set my arguments in MY_APPLICATION_OPTS in environment variable.